# What does it mean the fish objects on the architecture diagram?

Tags: enterprise-architecture, diagrams, data-flow-diagram

What does it mean this fish object on the architecture diagram?

[image]

Comment: Although I was able to answer because I'm familiar with the modeling notation that appears to be used, it's standard practice to indicate the modeling language used. If a standard modeling notation is used, it's pretty straightforward to obtain documentation on that notation. However, if it's a non-standard notation, the author needs to provide information on what colors and symbols mean somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an ArchiMate 3.1 diagram, those symbols are "Application Events". Application events represent changes in application state. You can find more information in the [ArchiMate 3.1 specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/archimate3-doc/toc.html), specifically in [Chapter 9 Application Layer](https://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/archimate3-doc/chap09.html).